# Proving convergence by definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I need to use definition of convergence to prove that this sequence converges.
$$ a_n=\sqrt{(n^2+n)}-\sqrt{(n^2-n)}$$
I know it converges to 1, so I start with
$$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists N \in \Bbb N)(\forall n >N) |a_n-1|<\epsilon$$
$$|\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2-n}-1|$$
I tried multiplying with
$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}$$
but it leads me nowhere. I know in the end I should compare it with some sequence that converges to zero, but I can't get to there.

Comment: What do you mean "compare it with a sequence that converges to zero"? That's what I'd try to do if, for example, I was trying to get the sequence's limit by the Squeeze Theorem, but how would that go if we need the definition, with $\;\epsilon>0\;$ and etc.?

Answer (score 1):

What you tried is exactly what we need here. It gives
$$a_n={2n\over\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}={2\over\sqrt{1+{1\over n}}+\sqrt{1-{1\over n}}}\to1\qquad(n\to\infty)\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

you can write $$\sqrt{n^2+n}-(\sqrt{n^2-n}+1)$$ and multiply by $$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2-n}+1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2-n}+1}$$

Comment: thank you again, corrected

Comment: I've done this, and I get $\frac {2n-2\sqrt{n^2-n}-1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2-n}+1}$, but don't know what is my next step. What can I can compare this to, to show it is greater than this expression?

Comment: multiply your expression $$\frac{2n-1-2\sqrt{n^2-n}}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2+n}+1}$$ by $$2n-1+2\sqrt{n^2-n}$$ (numerator and denominator)

Answer (score 0):

Let $b_n=\sqrt{n^2+n}$. Note that $a_n=b_n-b_{n-1}$.

For $0<q\le 1$, consider the expression $$\tag1\left(n+\frac q2\right)^2=n^2+ qn+\frac{q^2}4.$$ With $q=1$, the right hand side is $>n^2+ n$, hence
$$\tag2b_n<n+\frac12.$$
With $q=1-\frac1{4n}$, the right hand side in $(1)$ becomes $n^2+ n+\frac{q^2-1}4<n^2+ n$, hence
$$b_n>n+\frac12 -\frac1{8n}.$$
We conclude 
$$ a_n=b_n-b_{n-1}\begin{cases}<\left(n+\frac12\right)-\left(n-1+\frac12-\frac1{8(n-1)}\right)&=1+\frac1{8(n-1)}\\
>\left(n+\frac12-\frac1{8n}\right)-\left(n-1+\frac12\right)&=1-\frac1{8n}\end{cases}$$
and so for $\epsilon>0$ we have
$|a_n-1|<\epsilon $ as soon as $n>\frac 8\epsilon+1$.